# Check number of current slide

Tags: excel, vba

I have done a macro that entered a powerpoint, iterates through slides and if a slide has a chart, it opens the excel of it and changes some values.

But I am having a problem with doing specific functions on a specific slide number, the macro does not recognize the slide number and does the same operation to every slide.

Here's the not full code ( I just didn't add all because it probably too long):

```
'Iterate through slides
For Each sld In PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.Slides

    With sld.Shapes(1)

        If .HasChart Then
            Set oPPChart = .Chart
            Set oPPChartData = oPPChart.ChartData

            oPPChartData.Activate

            'Set Excel objects
            Set oXlWb = oPPChartData.Workbook
            Set oXlApp = oXlWb.Parent

            Call CalcCopyPaste(oXlWb)
            Call DeleteColumnLastUsed(oXlWb)

            'Remover headers
            Select Case OPCountry

                Case "US"

                    'Remover headers só!
                    If sld = 8 Then

                        Range("U5").Select                            
                        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
                        Selection.Cut
                        Range("C3").Select
                        ActiveSheet.Paste


                    Else
                        Range("S3").Select
                        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
                        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
                        Selection.Cut
                        Range("S1").Select
                        ActiveSheet.Paste

                    End If

            End Select

            oXlWb.Windows(1).Visible = False
            oXlApp.Visible = False

          End If

    End With

Next sld
```

So for the slide 8 it should do something specific has stated in the IF, but it does it all on every slide! 
can you help on this? thanks!

Comment: If you change that to `If sld.SlideNumber = 8 Then`, does that work?

Comment: What shows up if you put `msgbox(sld.slideNumber)`? (Or if you're using the debugger, `Debug.Print sld.SlideNumber`) right before that IF() statement?

Comment: If i put it on the start of the for it's shows the slides ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As proposed by BruceWayne I resolved by doing:

```
Select Case UCase(OPCountry)


            Case "US"
                'Conditions for slide 3, 4 and 5

                If sld.SlideNumber = 3 Or sld.SlideNumber = 4 Or sld.SlideNumber = 5 Or sld.SlideNumber = 6 Then

                    With sld.Shapes(1)

                        If .HasChart Then

                            Set oPPChart = .Chart
                            Set oPPChartData = oPPChart.ChartData

                            oPPChartData.Activate

                            'Set Excel objects
                            Set oXlWb = oPPChartData.Workbook
                            Set oXlApp = oXlWb.Parent
```

I just changed the `SlideNumber` to whatever I wanted the slide to be. I think the problem was in the compiler of the excel, because it had (probably) to many processes opened.